# Wordpress: Mamp not redirecting

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, mamp

So I changed from mysite.com to localhost:8888/mylocalsite/ in wp-options inside phpMyadmin (inside my database named wordpress)

Then I went to wp-config.php file and changed my username/password to root and DB name to wordpress.

Inside HTDOCS (my root directory), I created a folder named wordpress where I put in all my files.

Now, when I try to run it on MAMP, It does not redirect/change location of my link to localhost:8888/mylocalsite/ rather keep it to localhost:8888/wordpress/

Also, If I do something like localhost:8888/mylocalsite/ it says nothing found on the server.

How can I fix it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you flush the permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

Please rename wordpress folder to mylocalsite